# How to remove Back text from LeftNavigation Bar button in iOS keeping back icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I just want to keep back icon but not back text which used to coming with every view whenever we push any viewcontroller. I don't want to keep any text with back icon. I just want to show only back icon without any text and without using any specific image.

I don't want to edit text of backbutton title. I want to completely remove text from backbutton icon.

Answer (score 2):

In the interface builder set the back text to a space (" ").

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"";
```

if you are using storyboard then you can chage on navigation controller back button item

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"";` This code will won't work through out the app. Means I want to change it through out the app in a general form so as I don't need to change it in every single views.

Comment: As i know there is no way to change it through out the app. Because you inherit UINavigationController and it is set by default. But you can override it in each class you want.